# passing pivot table views to laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have seen some of the question here but none of them have solved my problem. I am confused. I have a many to many relation between community and idea model. it is saving values in pivot table perfectly but I am unable to fetch data to view.

**Idea Model:**

```
public function communities() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Community', "community_idea");
}
```

**Community model:**

```
public function ideas() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Idea', "community_idea");
}
```

**Store Post Function:**

```
//function for creating Idea
public function storePost(IdeaRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('idea_image')) {
        $filename = $request->file('idea_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $moveImage = $request->file('idea_image')->move('images/', $filename);
    }
    $idea = new Idea();
    $idea->idea_title = $request->input('idea_title');
    $idea->user_id = Auth::id();
    $idea->idea_image = $moveImage;
    $idea->idea_info = $request->input('idea_info');
    $idea->idea_location = $request->input('idea_location');
    $idea->idea_goal = $request->input('idea_goal');
    $idea->idea_description = strip_tags($request->input('idea_description'));
    $idea->save();
    $idea->communities()->attach($request->input('selection'));
    Session::set('idea_id',$idea->id);
    session()->flash('flash_message', 'Your idea has been submitted for Review, Kindly Fill this Work BreakDown of You Work');
    return redirect()->route('create_wbs');
}
```

**VIEW:**
When I try to use this, it throws:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$communities` error

```
@foreach($ideas->communities as $idea)
   @if($idea->status == 1)
     <div class="grid_3">
     <div class="project-short sml-thumb">

     <div class="top-project-info">
     <div class="content-info-short clearfix">
     <a href="{{URL::to('showidea', array($idea->id))}}" class="thumb-img">
     <img src="{{asset($idea->idea_image)}}" alt="{{$idea->idea_title}}">
     </a>
     <div class="wrap-short-detail">
     <h3 class="rs acticle-title"><a class="be-fc-orange" href="{{URL::to('showidea', array($idea->id))}}"><q>{{$idea->idea_title}}</q></a></h3>
     <p class="rs tiny-desc">by <a href="#" class="fw-b fc-gray be-fc-orange">{{$idea->User->name}}</a></p>
     <p class="rs title-description">{{$idea->idea_info}}</p>
     <p class="rs project-location">
     <i class="icon iLocation"></i>
     {{$idea->idea_location}}
     </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!--end: .grid_3 > .project-short-->
  @endif
@endforeach
```

**Edit:**

```
    public function showCommunities($id)
    {
        $community = Community::findOrFail($id);
        $communities = Community::all();
        $ideas = Idea::paginate(15);
//        $ideas->communities()->ideas;
        return view('publicPages.ideas_in_community', compact(['ideas', 'community', 'communities']));

    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

When i `var_dump` on `ideass` it displays following data.

[image: var_dump on ideass variable]

When i `var_dump` on `$idea` it displays following data

[image: var_dump on idea]

**View Code**

```
@foreach($ideas as $idea)
    @foreach($idea->communities as $ideass)
      @if($ideass->status == 1)
        <div class="grid_3">
        <div class="project-short sml-thumb">
        <div class="top-project-info">
        <div class="content-info-short clearfix">
        <a href="{{URL::to('showidea', array($idea->id))}}" class="thumb-img">
        <img src="{{asset($ideass->idea_image)}}" alt="{{$ideass->idea_title}}">
        </a>
        <div class="wrap-short-detail">
        <h3 class="rs acticle-title"><a class="be-fc-orange" href="{{URL::to('showidea', array($idea->id))}}"><q>{{$ideass->idea_title}}</q></a></h3>
        <p class="rs tiny-desc">by <a href="#" class="fw-b fc-gray be-fc-orange">{{$ideass->User->name}}</a></p>
        <p class="rs title-description">{{$ideass->idea_info}}</p>
        <p class="rs project-location">
        <i class="icon iLocation"></i>
        {{$ideass->idea_location}}
        </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div><!--end: .grid_3 > .project-short-->
      @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you get this error on **storePost()** or after that when you display the data from another method?

Comment: when i display this data then i get this error.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the method from the controller that loads this view.

Comment: Please check the edit. i dont know how i can fetch the associated data.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$ideas = Idea::paginate(15);` you get a paginator with many models, like a collection, so you can't do `$ideas->communities`. You have to loop all the Ideas and then to get the Communities of each one.

```
$ideas = Idea::with('communities')->paginate(15);

foreach ( $ideas as $idea ) {
    foreach ( $idea->communities as $community ) {
        //DO STUFF
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

`$ideas = Idea::paginate(15);` contains a collection with 15 records from the DB and each record has a *belongsToMany* relation with *App\Community*, which you have defined in the model. When you try `$ideas->communities` it doesn't work because `$ideas` is a collection, 15 records, and `communities` is the relation to a single *Idea* model, the collection doesn't know what `communities` is. So when you loop `foreach ( $ideas as $idea ) {` the variable `$idea` is a single *Idea* model and it has access to the *belongsToMany* relation with *App\Community*, so you can say `$idea->communities`.

Comment: could you please explain little more? confused if i dont add pagination then? i need a simple solution

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Let me try this :)

Comment: I have used your given code but it is not showing anything. i have used `foreach` loops in view.

Comment: @QasimAli what do you mean it's now showing anything? Implement this inside your *publicPages.ideas_in_community* view.

Comment: Yes i have implemented in idea_in_community when i var_dump() it shows whole (app/Idea) object but when trying to print it prints nothing

Comment: @QasimAli not sure what this means. Make sure Idea has records related to Community.